# Playframework reusable templates - version 2.6 and beyooooond

Tags: playframework

I just updated to play 2.6, and now none of my reusable templates work.

For example

In `index.scala.html` I had

```
@(word: String)

@main("My index Page"){
   <p>@word</p>
}
```

And in my `main.scala.html` I had

```
@(title: String, stuff: HTML)
//and then things here that did stuff that aren't needed for this example and, anyway, i made the whole thing up
```

The gist is that I get errors that say:

```
C:\file\path\index.scala.html:3: not found: value main
[error] @main("My index Page") {
```

I found this is resolved if I add `@this(path.to.main)` at the beginning, but I don't see that written in the play docs, so I'm not sure if I'm doing something right, or something wrong that just happens to work.

Comment: can you please check my answer - comment if you still have problems or accept it otherwise? So it helps others and gives me feedback if my answer are correct or at least help.

Comment: @pme sure - but it wasn't quite the answer i needed

Comment: @pme but thanks for the answer! i upvoted you anyway!

Comment: thanks for clearing things up - at least you used the proposed currying;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in play 2.6, they've changed the way that variables are passed around.

There is apparently no "global" pool of data, whatever that means, so now to call the "main" (or any other template)  i need to do this:

1. In my controller, import the view *that uses the main*
2. In my controller, *make that view a parameter to the controller constuctor*
3. In my controller, assign the parameter to a member variable value
4. In the view, after any imports i need @this(the_external_template_to_be_used)
5. In my view, i need my usual @(...) as ever

I love examples, here is one.

Controller is called DemoController, the view it calls is demoView.scala.html, and within *that* view we send data to mainView.scala.html

You can think of the mainView as having the scaffolding - the banner, the lhs menu etc, and demoView having the content - whatever it might be.

Alright, first the controller:

```
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import views.html.demoView; //i put the demoView.scala.html in an html folder!

public class HomeController extends Controller {
    private demoView demoView; //yes, a private member for the view
    @Inject //you need this! 
    public HomeController(views.html.demoView demoView){
        this.demoView = demoView;
    }

    public Result addLesson(){
        return ok(demoView.render("words words words"));
    }
}
```

Now the View:

```
@* i dont import anything, but if i did it would be here *@

@* need this to call another template in 2.6++ *@
@this(main:views.html.main) 

@* everything from here is as usual*@
@(importantMessage: String)
    @main("My Title") {
        <p>@importantMessage</p>
    }
```

Now the main:

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
    @* do your html better than this! *@
    <title>@title</title>
    @content
</html>
```

**If you don't use another template in your template, you don't need to do any of this! You can just import the template in the controller and call the render method - no need to inject etc!**

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your main to

```
@(title: String)(stuff: HTML)
```

> using currying

This is what you are calling here:

```
 @main("My index Page"){
   <p>@word</p>
}
```

> see your brackets